# Laravel generate get route with parameters with data from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am sedindg an ajax request to get products like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('filter-products') }}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', filters: filters, category_id: {{ $category->id }} }
})
.done(function(products) {
    console.log(products)

    let html = ''
    for(product of products) {
        html += '<div class="col-md-4 women-grids wp1 animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">' 
            html += '<a href="product-route-here">'

            html += '<div class="product-img">'
                html += 
            html += '</div>'

            html += '</div>'
            console.log(html)
    }
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error")
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete")
})
```

My Route :

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product');
```

The problem is with the `<a href>` which I need to generate for the product link
in laravel when I print the products I will call it like this `route('product', $product->id)` but in that case how do I pass the product id to the route function to generate the link?

Comment: show your routing code

Comment: `Route::get('/product/{slug}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product');` it is not id it is slug but I think it doesnt matter

Comment: `html += '<a href="product-route-here">'` do you want to use route here ?

Comment: yes
the problem is that I dont know how to pass the product slug as parameter

Comment: where is you AJAX code? in javascript file or in a view file?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `id` in `product` Change from

```
html += '<a href="product-route-here">'
```

To

```
html += '<a href="/product/"'+product.id+'>'
```

Also use termination sign colon `;` at the end it will help if you are going to make minified js.

Answer (score 2):

If your ajax code is located on `blade` file then add below line in that view file. This line will generate url till product, then you can concat with your id in your ajax code.

`<script>var product_url = "{{url(' / ')}}/product/";</script>`

After adding above line use `product_url` variable in your ajax code like below code.

`html += '<a href="' + product_url + product.product_id + '">'`